# iOS - Autolayout from Landscape to Portrait

Tags: iphone, xcode, autolayout

I've designed a xib for iPhone in Landscape mode which has a fullscreen view containing many subviews.

Is it possible to automatically adapt it to Portrait as sketched here: http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/5523/5cxw.jpg without having to create tons of contraints for each subview?

Comment: Split your interface to blocks which internal constraints stay right in any orientation, this will reduce amount of invalid constraints. If it impossible (very rare case) you can use this way: hide main view at start of rotation, load proper main view controller for new layout and then show it.

Comment: In attached image you have not more than 4 constraints need to be updated at rotation. Where is 'tons'?

Answer (score 1):

Enclose all the subviews in the new `UIView`. Set leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints between the new view and the main view. Then in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` set correct `constant`'s of these constraints. In landscape they should all be equal to 0. In portrait set them accordingly to get the look you're looking for.

Comment: I've tried both your proposal as well as the @Igor one and, due to my lack of knowledge about auto-layout, things were getting quite complicated; instead of fighting with constraints and their conflicts, I gave a try to Springs&Struts turning off auto-layout: just giving `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` to all the subviews I achieved the desired result.
I will definitely go more in depth with auto-layout for future projects, but in this case Springs&Struts seemed the easiest way to go.

Comment: @DAN: Sure, Auto Layout requires some learning upfront - the lectures from WWDC 2012 & 2013 and the documentation are a must.